# Join Where Rows Don't Exist or Where Criteria Matches...?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm trying to write a query to tell me which orders have valid promocodes. Promocodes are only valid between certain dates and **optionally** certain packages.

I'm having trouble even explaining how this works (see psudo-ish code below) but basically if there are packages associated with a promocode then the order has to have one of those packages and be within a valid date range otherwise it just has to be in a valid date range.

The whole "if PrmoPackage rows exist" thing is really throwing me off and I feel like I should be able to do this without a whole bunch of `Union`s. (I'm not even sure if that would make it easier at this point...)

Anybody have any ideas for the query?

```
if `OrderPromoCode` = `PromoCode`

    then if `OrderTimestamp` is between `PromoStartTimestamp` and `PromoEndTimestamp`

        then if `PromoCode` has packages associated with it
            //yes
                then if `PackageID` is one of the specified packages
                    //yes
                        code is valid
                    //no
                        invalid
            //no
                code is valid
```

Order:

```
OrderID* | OrderTimestamp | PackageID | OrderPromoCode
1        | 1/2/11         | 1         | ABC
2        | 1/3/11         | 2         | ABC
3        | 3/2/11         | 2         | DEF
4        | 4/2/11         | 3         | GHI
```

Promo:

```
PromoCode* | PromoStartTimestamp* | PromoEndTimestamp*
ABC        | 1/1/11               | 2/1/11
ABC        | 3/1/11               | 4/1/11
DEF        | 1/1/11               | 1/11/13
GHI        | 1/1/11               | 1/11/13
```

PromoPackage:

```
PromoCode* | PromoStartTimestamp* | PromoEndTimestamp* | PackageID*
ABC        | 1/1/11               | 2/1/11             | 1
ABC        | 1/1/11               | 2/1/11             | 3
GHI        | 1/1/11               | 1/11/13            | 1
```

Desired Result:

```
OrderID | IsPromoCodeValid
1       | 1
2       | 0
3       | 1
4       | 0
```

Comment: Why do both Promo and PromoPackage have start and end dates? Do they ever vary?

Comment: ABC could be valid in January 2011, March 2011, December 2011, April 2057....

Comment: So...is the PackageID column on the Order table nullable?  If not, then in what situation would the start and end dates on the Promo table ever matter?  Ah, I supposed in the case of DEF, where there is no associated PromoPackage record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH PromoCTE AS
(   SELECT  promo.*, CASE WHEN p.PromoCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [HasPackage]
    FROM    Promo
            LEFT JOIN
            (   SELECT  DISTINCT PromoCode
                FROM    PromoPackage
            ) p
                ON promo.PromoCode = p.PromoCode
)
SELECT  [Order].OrderID, 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN HasPackage = 1 THEN PromoPackage.PromoCode ELSE Promo.PromoCode END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsPromoCodeValid]
FROM    [Order]
        LEFT JOIN PromoCTE promo
            ON Promo.PromoCode = [Order].OrderPromoCode
            AND [Order].OrderTimeStamp BETWEEN Promo.PromoStartTimestamp AND Promo.PromoEndTimestamp
        LEFT JOIN PromoPackage
            ON PromoPackage.PromoCode = OrderPromoCode
            AND PromoPackage.PackageID = [Order].PackageID
            AND [Order].OrderTimeStamp BETWEEN PromoPackage.PromoStartTimestamp AND PromoPackage.PromoEndTimestamp
GROUP BY [Order].OrderID;
```

**NON CTE VERSION**

```
SELECT  [Order].OrderID, 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN HasPackage = 1 THEN PromoPackage.PromoCode ELSE Promo.PromoCode END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsPromoCodeValid]
FROM    [Order]
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  promo.*, CASE WHEN p.PromoCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [HasPackage]
            FROM    Promo
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (   SELECT  DISTINCT PromoCode
                        FROM    PromoPackage
                    ) p
                        ON promo.PromoCode = p.PromoCode
        ) promo
            ON Promo.PromoCode = [Order].OrderPromoCode
            AND [Order].OrderTimeStamp BETWEEN Promo.PromoStartTimestamp AND Promo.PromoEndTimestamp
        LEFT JOIN PromoPackage
            ON PromoPackage.PromoCode = OrderPromoCode
            AND PromoPackage.PackageID = [Order].PackageID
            AND [Order].OrderTimeStamp BETWEEN PromoPackage.PromoStartTimestamp AND PromoPackage.PromoEndTimestamp
GROUP BY [Order].OrderID;
```

Comment: This also doesn't account for the scenario of a valid order that has no packages associated with it.  In your query if there's no package it's always invalid.

Comment: @JNK I have corrected this now, and I think this is now the only solution so far that correctly deals with the OPs criteria. Demonstrated [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70fd4/4) (note order 4 shows as valid in accepted answer and not in mine).

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to make a view with this query... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3115379/screengrab_20120404192746.png

Comment: Does PromoPackage contain a column called PromoCode? The error implies that the column or table name is wrong.

Comment: @GarethD yes, PromoPackage contains a column PromoCode, it works when I run it in a new query window but throws that error when I paste it into a view...? any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating your view? Seems to work fine [for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23c4d/1)

Comment: I added unique variable names for all the tables and it works now, thanks for all the help I'll upvote

Answer (score 3):

Agh....I think there are a few ways to do it:

Here's a somewhat messy approach using a couple of left outer joins, a group by, and a case statement

```
SELECT [Order].OrderID, CASE count(isnull(Promo.PromoCode, PromoPackage.PromoCode)) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM [Order]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Promo ON
    Promo.PromoCode = [Order].OrderPromoCode
    AND [Order].OrderTimestamp BETWEEN Promo.PromoStartTimestamp and Promo.PromoEndTimestamp
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PromoPackage WHERE PromoPackage.PromoCode = Promo.PromoCode)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PromoPackage ON
    PromoPackage.PromoCode = [Order].OrderPromoCode
    AND PromoPackage.PackageID = [Order].PackageID
    AND [Order].OrderTimestamp BETWEEN PromoPackage.PromoStartTimestamp and PromoPackage.PromoEndTimestamp
GROUP BY
    [Order].OrderID
```

You might be able to do this in a cleaner manner using a CTE.

EDIT: updated with a query using a CTE

```
WITH OrderPromo (OrderID, PromoCode, PackageID)
AS
(
SELECT [Order].OrderID, Promo.PromoCode, null
FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN Promo ON
    [Order].OrderPromoCode = Promo.PromoCode
    AND [Order].OrderTimestamp BETWEEN Promo.PromoStartTimestamp AND Promo.PromoEndTimestamp
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PromoPackage WHERE PromoPackage.PromoCode = Promo.PromoCode)

UNION ALL

SELECT [Order].OrderID, PromoPackage.PromoCode, PromoPackage.PackageID
FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN PromoPackage ON
    [Order].OrderPromoCode = PromoPackage.PromoCode
    AND [Order].PackageID = PromoPackage.PackageID
    AND [Order].OrderTimestamp BETWEEN PromoPackage.PromoStartTimestamp AND PromoPackage.PromoEndTimestamp
)
SELECT [Order].OrderID, 1
FROM [Order]
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrderPromo WHERE OrderPromo.OrderID = [Order].OrderID)

UNION ALL

SELECT [Order].OrderID, 0
FROM [Order]
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrderPromo WHERE OrderPromo.OrderID = [Order].OrderID)
;
```

EDIT: one more solution.  This one creates a "Promotion" table by combining the Promo and PromoPackage tables.  Promo records that have no associated PromoPackage record effectively have a PackageID of null.

```
SELECT
  [Order].OrderID,
  CASE count(Promotion.PromoCode) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM [Order]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      Promo.PromoCode,
      PromoPackage.PackageID,
      isnull(PromoPackage.PromoStartTimestamp, Promo.PromoStartTimestamp) as PromoStartTimestamp,
      isnull(PromoPackage.PromoEndTimestamp, Promo.PromoEndTimestamp) as PromoEndTimestamp
  FROM Promo
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PromoPackage ON
      Promo.PromoCode = PromoPackage.PromoCode
) Promotion ON
    Promotion.PromoCode = [Order].OrderPromoCode
    AND (Promotion.PackageID is null OR Promotion.PackageID = [Order].PackageID)
    AND [Order].OrderTimestamp BETWEEN Promotion.PromoStartTimestamp AND Promotion.PromoEndTimestamp
GROUP BY
  [Order].OrderID
```

Comment: +1 - I think you are the only person who both answered AND read the question, as this is the only query I see that accounts for both the OP's scenarios appropriately.

Comment: thank you sir, it looks like it's working, and @JNK thank you for reviewing answers

Comment: This returns order 4 as being valid? Surely that is not the required behaviour?

Comment: @GarethD Hmm, I think order 4 should have a valid promo, right?  The order date is 4/2/2011, which falls between promotion dates 1/1/11 and 1/11/13 for promo code GHI, package ID 1.  If that is the case, then the desired result in the question is incorrect, or the example data is incorrect.

Comment: @GarethD is correct. This query is incorrect. Order 4 should not be valid because GHI is only valid on package 1

Comment: Hmm, I think we are understanding the requirements differently, then. My understanding was that the promotion was valid if the order date fell within the date range of a promotion in either the Promo table or the PromoPackage table. Also, on second glance, it looks like the order date for order #4 falls within the date range for the "GHI" records in both the Promo table and the PromoPackage table.

Comment: It falls within the date range but fails the promopackage because there is a promopackage defined, I know this query is a pain in the ass, I didn't make that clear in my post

Comment: Doh! My appologies.  I missed the fact that the Order table also has a PackageID column.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As I understand it DEF is valid on all packages between the dates defined in the promo table because there is no entry for promo code DEF in promopackage. GHI is only valid on package 1 because there is an entry in the promopackage table.

Comment: This latest edit doesn't work either. Order 4 still shows as valid, you need to exclude promocodes with a package from the top half of the union within the CTE.

Comment: @GarethD Ah, right. I see that it's still valid due to the GHI record in the Promo table. I suppose the phrase "and optionally certain packages" is partly what threw me off.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice It took me a couple of attempts to get there too. I think I got there in the end. There is some sample data on  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70fd4/5) if it helps

Comment: @GarethD THANK YOUUUUUUUUU IT WORKSSSSS. I didnt know there was an SQLfiddle.com either

Comment: @GarethD I saw your link to SQL Fiddle, and I did find it very helpful, as well as your comments to help understand the requirements.  Thank you very much, and +1 on your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this via correlated subquery. I didn't test this, but:

```
SELECT  
    a.OrderID,
    CASE WHEN 0 <= (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM PromoCode x
            JOIN PromoPackage y
                ON y.PromoCode = x.PromoCOde
                AND a.OrderTimeStamp BETWEEN y.PromoSTartTimestamp AND y.PromoEndTimestamp
            WHERE
                x.PromoCode = a.OrderPromoCode              
        ) THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS 'IsPromoCodeValid'

FROM    
    Order a
```

Comment: This does not account for the valid timestamp but no packages scenario

Comment: Ahh, I didn't read the question correctly. Dr. Wiley Apprentice's answer seems to be the best solution.

Comment: In your defense it's a pretty convoluted requirement

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try recreating your tables, but this query should come close

```
SELECT o.OrderID, case ISNULL(pck.PackageID, 0) when 0 then 0 else 1 end as IsPromoCodeValid
FROM [Order] as o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Promo] as p ON
o.OrderPromoCode = p.PromoCode AND o.OrderTimestamp >= p.PromoStartTimestamp AND o.OrderTimestamp <= p.PromoStartTimestamp
LEFT OUTER JOIN [PromoPackage] pck ON  o.PackageID = pck.PackageID AND p.PromoCode = pck.PromoCode
```

Comment: This also doesn't account for the scenario of a valid order that has no packages associated with it. In your query if there's no package it's always invalid

Comment: All you would have to do in that case would be to modify the case statement.  Have you tried comparing execution times?  My proposed solution does not require any UNIONS and with LEFT JOINS on primary keys it should be pretty fast.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work (untested):

```
select o.OrderID,
  isPromoCodeValid = 
    isnull((select 1 from Promo p where o.OrderTimestamp >= p.PromoStartTimestamp and o.OrderTimestamp <= p.PromoEndTimestamp), 0)
    or isnull((select 1 from PromoPackage pp where o.OrderTimestamp >= pp.PromoStartTimestamp and o.OrderTimestamp <= pp.PromoEndTimestamp and o.PackageID = pp.PackageID), 0)
from orders o
```

Comment: This will return valid even if the promo has packages that aren't met, as long as the dates line up.